# Variation on Social Golfers

Tags: co.combinatorics

This is a problem I ran across recently while trying to schedule classes which I thought might be interesting theoretically.

Given `k` golfers who want to play on `m` courts for `n` weeks, is it possible to arrange groups of golfers of fixed size `s` (where `s` can possibly be smaller than `m/k`) such that every golfer plays on every court, and every golfer plays every week?

I'm actually trying to solve this for k=24, m=n=7, s=6

Is there an equivalent or similar problem I should look at?  Is there a way to solve this for small `n` so I can get my personal version done in time for the classes?

Comment: "golf" ? "court" ? do you mean tennis ? or squash ?

Comment: Perhaps course or links.